# How to set a textbox to align to the left?

Tags: html, css, alignment

My [website](http://xiexianhui.com/syndicate/) has a contact form where I want the input fields be lined up to the left, currently they are to the right. I am not good at css, I can't even find out what element I should change attribute, although I know it's an easy job using FireBug. Can someone tell me how? Thank you so much.

Comment: Personally I did this with the built-in web development features in Google Chrome. If you want to know how to do it in firebug, look at "introduction to firebug" at http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1):

In **neon.css** remove the entry `float: right;` from the respective style definitions. Of course you will then have to position them to lign up beneath eachother.

```
.foxform input, .foxform textarea {
    ...
    float: right; <-- remove this
}

.fox-dropdown-container {
    ...
    float: right; <-- and remove this
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I make all the inputs to the left but now they are aligned scraggly jagged, how can I make all the inputs beneath the their respective questions? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`text-align: left;` or `float: left;`

Comment: `float: left` should be applied to the `input.foxtext` class, or `.foxform input`.